# How can I find out what file Visual Studio is complaining about when I commit changes that it says contain a large file

Tags: visual-studio, github

Recently Visual Studio has started flashing up a message saying that I'm committing a large file (or similar to that) - problem is the message vanishes so quickly I can't read it.

How can I find out what file it is complaining about.

Similarly for file rename warnings?